# show that there is a linear map $S:V \longrightarrow V$ such that $S(v_i) = w_i$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I am stuck on the first part of (b). I don't quite understand what I'm meant to show.

Take $v$ in $V$.

$$v = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + ... + a_n v_n$$

Then,

$$S(v) = a_1 S(v_1) + a_2 S(v_2) + ... + a_n S(v_n)= a_1 w_1 + a_2 w_2 + ... + a_n w_n$$

Is this what I'm meant to show?

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't *use* the fact that $S v_i = w_i$ in your proof, because that's exactly what you need to show! You need to show the *existence* of a linear map S such that $S v_i = w_i \;\forall 1\le i\le n$.

Comment: No, you need to show that such an $S$ exists. For instance, here's an easy example. Suppose the $v_i$'s are just the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$; i.e. $v_1 = (1,0,\dots,0)^T$, $v_2 = (0,1,0,\dots,0)^T$, etc. Then the matrix for $S$ would just have the $w_i$'s as columns. Now do this in general, and without resorting to matrices.

Comment: I'm leaning toward saying "almost".  The reason is, it is trivial to show that there is a function $S$ which maps $v_i$ to $w_i$.  The tricky bit is showing that $S$ is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V,$ then for each $v\in V,$ there exist unique $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\Bbb R$ such that $$v=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n.$$ For any such $v,$ let $$S(v)=a_1w_1+\cdots+a_nw_n.$$ You need to show that $S$ is a well-defined map $V\to V,$ that $S(v_i)=w_i$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\},$ and that $S$ is linear.

Comment: You're very welcome. The linearity is probably the trickiest part to show, but even that is fairly straightforward. Let me know if you have any trouble, and I'll try to get you unstuck.